# redirect() and NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write correct redirection to other view, but now I have no idea

This is my last try:

txt2png/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('txt2png.views',
# ...
    url(r'^list/(?P<what>\w)/', 'list', name='list-notes'),
    url(r'^search/', 'search', name='search-notes'),
)
```

txt2png/views.py

```
def list(request, what):
# ...
def search(request):
#...
    return redirect(list, 'search')
```

Comment: And? You did not specify what is wrong with your current solution - what did you expect that would happen, and really happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the `.../list/anything/`   ?
It is 404, because of your url config. The `(?P<what>\w)` means only ONE character, so `.../list/a/` will work.

Replace that row in your url config:

```
url(r'^list/(?P<what>\w+)/', list, name='list-notes'),
```

(a + sign added to the regex)